# When Use cursor in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

When And why use Cursor in your project?

If I have this Mock code

```
var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


mongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tut3',function(err,db){
    if(err)throw err;

    var collection = db.collection('messages');


    collection.find({},{_id:true}).each(function(err,doc){
        console.log("---- CLASSIC ----")
        console.dir(doc);
            //stuff//
    });

    var cursor = collection.find({},{_id:true});

    cursor.each(function(err,doc){
        console.log("---- CURSOR ----")
        console.dir(doc);
        //stuff2
    });

})
```

The collection messages is huge for example.

Which different between `//stuff`and `//stuff2`

I know that if I do

```
var cursor = collection.find({},{_id:true});
```

I Know that when cursor return I Have all the documents (synchronous) and it has many [methods](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html), but also inside `stuff`, the query is complete and I have all Documents...

Where is the difference? and when use `var cursor` instead the "classic" `find`?

Comment: What does "classic find" mean to you? The shell? That returns a cursor as well. The fact that the shell is a REPL is the reason you see results straight away, since it calls next for you and with a default "batch size" of 25.

Comment: No Sorry, I mean `collection.find({},{_id:true}).each(function(err,doc){` with `each` inside a `query`. I know that it's a cursor. but i don't understand the difference between `each`inside a query instead `var cursor = query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between

```
 cursor = collection.find();
```

and:

```
collection.find().each(function(err,doc) {
```

Is basically what is called "method chaining". It's really just an opinion of how you want to write your code. So what is being acted on with methods such as `.each()` is still just a cursor object that could have optionally be returned on the left hand side.

Also the "cursor" has not yet been "executed" until such a method is called. This means that "modifiers" can be applied without executing yet, as in:

```
cursor = cursor.skip(10);
cursor = cursor.limit(100);
```

As all modifiers will also return to the left a cursor.

This is essentially the principle applied in "method chaining", where whatever "type" is returned from the left can be "chained" on the right:

```
collection.find().skip(10).limit(100).each(function(err,doc) {
```

If you are dealing with "small" sets of results you can just call the `.toArray()` method on the cursor:

```
collection.find({},{_id:true}).toArray(function(err,array) {
   console.log( array ); // everything
});
```

But if have value 1000's or millions of results, you probably don't want to load all of that in memory. This is where you process with an iterator:

```
collection.find({},{_id:true}).each(function(err,doc) {
    // do something with the current doc
});
```

Iteration is why cursors exist.

Comment: Perfect ! thanks You ! Last Question. In this [code](http://pastebin.com/bNptQXDU) when I check `count` return ALL documents.Why?  
`

Comment: @PaulSantone Take a look at the [manual page](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#count). `.count()` takes two arguments as in `.count(applySkipLimit,callback)`. The default and what happens when the first is not supplied is the consideration is `false` and no modifier is applied. Basically what I said above, the cursor has not executed yet and only methods like `.count()` `.each()` `.toArray()` actually execute. `.count(true,function(err,count) {` applies any modifiers.

Comment: Thanks again! I had not seen in Doc. Thanks